# Como reproduzir query com subqueries do MySQL no hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Estou utilizando JPA 2.0 e tentando reproduzir esta query no hibernate , mas não estou conseguindo visualizar como fazer.

Fiz na linguagem do Mysql

```
SELECT totalassociado, 
       totalcriticado, 
       items.item_codigo_item, 
       items.item_data_item, 
       items.item_descricao, 
       items.item_status, 
       items.empresa, 
       items.usuario_nome, 
       Associado.usuario_codigo, 
       items.usuario_codigo 
FROM   (SELECT Count(item.`codigo`)          AS TotalAssociado, 
               item.`codigo_item`            AS item_codigo_item, 
               item.`data_item`              AS item_data_item, 
               item.`descricao`              AS item_descricao, 
               item.`status`                 AS item_status, 
               item.codigo_empresa, 
               usuario.`codigo`              AS usuario_codigo, 
               usuario.`nome`                AS usuario_nome, 
               usuario.`permissao`           AS usuario_permissao, 
               tecnico_item.`codigo_tecnico` AS tecnico_item_codigo_tecnico, 
               tecnico_item.`codigo_item`    AS tecnico_item_codigo_item 
        FROM   `item` item 
               INNER JOIN `tecnico_item` tecnico_item 
                       ON item.`codigo` = tecnico_item.`codigo_item` 
               INNER JOIN `usuario` usuario 
                       ON tecnico_item.`codigo_tecnico` = usuario.`codigo` 
        GROUP  BY usuario.codigo, 
                  item.codigo_empresa) AS Associado, 
       (SELECT Count(item.`codigo`)          AS TotalCriticado, 
               item.`codigo_item`            AS item_codigo_item, 
               item.`data_item`              AS item_data_item, 
               item.`descricao`              AS item_descricao, 
               item.`status`                 AS item_status, 
               usuario.`codigo`              AS usuario_codigo, 
               usuario.`nome`                AS usuario_nome, 
               usuario.`permissao`           AS usuario_permissao, 
               tecnico_item.`codigo_tecnico` AS tecnico_item_codigo_tecnico, 
               tecnico_item.`codigo_item`    AS tecnico_item_codigo_item 
        FROM   `item` item 
               JOIN `tecnico_item` tecnico_item 
                 ON item.`codigo` = tecnico_item.`codigo_item` 
               JOIN `usuario` usuario 
                 ON tecnico_item.`codigo_tecnico` = usuario.`codigo` 
        WHERE  item.status = 'CRITICADO') AS Criticado, 
       (SELECT item.`codigo`                 AS item_codigo, 
               item.`codigo_item`            AS item_codigo_item, 
               item.`data_item`              AS item_data_item, 
               item.`descricao`              AS item_descricao, 
               item.`status`                 AS item_status, 
               item.codigo_empresa           AS Empresa, 
               usuario.`codigo`              AS usuario_codigo, 
               usuario.`nome`                AS usuario_nome, 
               usuario.`permissao`           AS usuario_permissao, 
               tecnico_item.`codigo_tecnico` AS tecnico_item_codigo_tecnico, 
               tecnico_item.`codigo_item`    AS tecnico_item_codigo_item 
        FROM   `item` item 
               JOIN `tecnico_item` tecnico_item 
                 ON item.`codigo` = tecnico_item.`codigo_item` 
               JOIN `usuario` usuario 
                 ON tecnico_item.`codigo_tecnico` = usuario.`codigo`) AS items 
WHERE  Associado.usuario_codigo = items.usuario_codigo
```

Alguém poderia dar uma ideia / ajuda?

```
ainda não consegui fazer a complicação está justamente em passar para jpql ou hql na hora de utilizar a sintaxe comecei assim:Query query = manager
            .createQuery(
                    "select m,d from (select m from Item m left join  m.tecnicos t "
                            + "where (m.status ='CRITICADO' or m.status ='JUSTIFICADO') and t.codigo=:codigo ) as m,"
                            + "(select d from Item d join d.tecnicos t where t.codigo=:codigo) as d",
                    Object[].class).setParameter("codigo", 3L);

    List<Object[]> items = query.getResultList();
    System.out.println("---Impressão de Items----");
    int i = 0;
    for (Object[] item : items)
        System.out.println(++i + " ITem  : "
                + ((Item) item[0]).getDescricao() + "Quantidade ===>  "
                + ((Item) item[1]).getDescricao());
}e recebi a mensagem:2014-03-21 11:46:25,161 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] line 1:17: unexpected token: m
```

2014-03-21 11:46:25,162 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] line 1:17: unexpected token: m
line 1:17: unexpected token: m ou ( retirando o mapeamento m

Comment: Poderia compartilhar conosco o que você já tentou no Hibernate? Você fez por meio de uma query HQL? Se sim, poderias postar a query e o erro que você encontrou?

Comment: ainda não consegui fazer a complicação está justamente em passar para jpql ou hql na hora de utilizar a sintaxe

Comment: coloquei acima o que tentei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o HQL (Hibernate Query Language) para este fim - o HQL possui uma sintaxe muito próxima do SQL e também suporta sub-query's:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

Ainda assim, no HQL você terá que fazer algumas adaptações, tais como:

- [Sintaxe do Join](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-examples);
- Alterar o nome das tabelas para o nome completo das classes Pojo (remover os delimitadores / crase);
- Das colunas relacionadas na cláusula `WHERE` e que são mapeadas como chave-estrangeira deverão receber as respectivas classes POJO como parâmetros;